# OpenCover does not cover under TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, opencover

I have a project that does NOT give me any coverage in the output coverage file when running under TeamCity.  When I run from the command line it covers fine.  Apparently there is some permission problem with the local system account that is used when TeamCity runs, ie if I change the TeamCity runner to use one of the logins I use to accesss the machine it gives coverage.  However I don't want to maintain the password of that user in the TeamCity service.

I'm using the -register:user param when kicking OpenCover off in the nant script, that doesn't help.

What is the recommended setup to get the coverage working when running under TeamCity ?

Comment: Did you try preregister profiler using regsvr32 manually?

Comment: Can you turn your comment into an answer, it worked.  I tried first to just go to dos prompt and register > regsvr32 OpenCover.Profiler.dll  that wouldn't work gave me error 0x80070005  The trick was to open the dos command prompt as admin then run the regsvr32 again and voila.  After that I kicked off a build in TeamCity and the coverage showed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preregister OpenCover.Profiler.dll using regsvr32 manually. But to execute this you should run cmd with admin rights.

Comment: Yes indeed - I tried first to just go to dos prompt and register > regsvr32 OpenCover.Profiler.dll that wouldn't work gave me error 0x80070005 The trick was to open the dos command prompt as admin then run the regsvr32 again and voila. After that I kicked off a build in TeamCity and the coverage showed up

Comment: I believe this is documented with the OpenCover documentation that comes with OpenCover (zip, msi)

Answer (score 4):

I recently set this up with MSBuild and it is working fine. Here are the relevant parts of my MSBuild script:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build;Test;Archive;" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <UsingTask AssemblyFile=
        "..\..\tools\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll"
        TaskName="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Xslt" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--Default Configuration-->
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>

    <!--Default Platform-->
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">"Any CPU"</Platform>

    <!--Test assemblies-->
    <TestAssemblies>HelloWorld.Mvc3UI.UnitTests\bin\$(Configuration)\HelloWorld.Mvc3UI.UnitTests.dll</TestAssemblies>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Targets="Clean;Rebuild" Projects="HelloWorld.sln"  ContinueOnError="false"/>
  </Target>

    <Target Name="Test">

        <!-- Check Code Coverage -->
        <Exec Command="..\..\tools\OpenCover.4.0.519\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:..\..\tools\NUnit\nunit-console.exe -targetargs:&quot;$(TestAssemblies) /xml=NUnitReport.xml /noshadow&quot; -filter:&quot;+[HelloWorld.Mvc3UI*]* -[HelloWorld.Mvc3UI.UnitTests*]*&quot; -output:OpenCoverReport.xml"></Exec>
        <!-- Format Code Coverage Report -->
        <Exec Command="..\..\tools\ReportGenerator.1.5.0.0\ReportGenerator.exe OpenCoverReport.xml OpenCoverReport"></Exec>

        <Xslt Inputs="NUnitReport.xml"
            Xsl="..\..\tools\NUnit\NUnitReport.xsl"
            Output="NUnitReport.html" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Archive">
        <Exec Command="..\..\tools\7-Zip.9.20\7za.exe a build.zip &quot;HelloWorld.Mvc3UI\*&quot;"></Exec>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

The key is to use the /noshadow option for NUnit and to use the -register switch for OpenCover (it requires COM registration to run, but this switch does a temporary registration for the TeamCity user account).

To prevent OpenCover from hanging sometimes, it also helps to disable .NET 2.0 in the nunit-console.exe.config file as a supported runtime as outlined [here](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/issues/94):

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <!-- Comment out the next line to force use of .NET 4.0 -->
    <!-- <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> -->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
```

Comment: I'm using Gallio runner and MbUnit tests, the answer from @Pavel worked for me.